getBoundingClientRect() returns the same values for different elements
This is my first project with HTML so, I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.
I have a column of images on the left and right and between them a column of text.
My problem is in the adjustImageVisibility() function.
I want to get the position of each image because I want to hide images that are lower then the text.
I managed to get the position for the last element in the text column, but when I check the positions for the images, img.getBoundingClientRect() gives the same values for each image.
bottom : -134.1999969482422
height : 0
left   : 5
right  : 5
top    : -134.1999969482422
width  : 0
x      : 5
y      : -134.1999969482422

The images are all 512 × 768 px and renderd as 127 × 190 px.
Here is my code snippet


const imageFolder = 'images/'; // Path to the local folder containing the images
const totalImages = 26; // (Total number of images in the folder) / 2

// Function to pad image name with zeros
function padImgName(i) {
  let imgName;
  if (i < 10) {
    imgName = `00${i}`;
  } else if (i < 100) {
    imgName = `0${i}`;
  } else {
    imgName = `${i}`;
  }
  return imgName;
}

// Function to load images from the local folder
function loadImages() {
  const leftImages = document.getElementById('left images');
  const rightImages = document.getElementById('right images');

  // Assuming images are named as 000.jpg, 001.jpg, etc.
  var imageNumber = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i <= totalImages; i++) {
    // left
    const leftImg = document.createElement('img');
    const leftImgName = padImgName(imageNumber);

    leftImg.src = `${imageFolder}${leftImgName}.jpeg`;
    leftImg.alt = `Image ${i} left`;
    leftImg.id  = `Image ${i} left`;

    leftImages.appendChild(leftImg);

    imageNumber++;

    // right
    if (imageNumber <= totalImages * 2) {
      const rightImg     = document.createElement('img');
      const rightImgName = padImgName(imageNumber);

      rightImg.src = `${imageFolder}${rightImgName}.jpeg`;
      rightImg.alt = `Image ${i} right`;
      rightImg.id  = `Image ${i} right`;

      rightImages.appendChild(rightImg);

      imageNumber++;
    }
  }
}

// Function to adjust the visibility of the images
function adjustImageVisibility() {

  // get bottom of Text 
  const centerDiv   = document.getElementById('center text');
  const lastElement = centerDiv.lastElementChild;
  const rect        = lastElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  const textBottom  = rect.bottom + window.scrollY;
  console.log(textBottom);

  // left
  for (let i = 0; i <= totalImages; i++) {
    const img  = document.getElementById(`Image ${i} right`);
    const rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(rect);
  }
}

// Load images from the local folder when the page loads
window.onload = function() {
  loadImages();
  adjustImageVisibility();
};
/* --------------- body --------------- */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}


/* --------------- unused --------------- */

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Stack items vertically */
  align-items: top;
  justify-content: top;
}


/* --------------- columns --------------- */

.left,
.right {
  /* for the images */
  width: 20%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.center {
  /* for the text */
  width: 100%;
  /* Adjusted to fill the remaining space */
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}


/* --------------- images --------------- */

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}


/* --------------- title --------------- */

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}


/* --------------- horizontal lines --------------- */

hr {
  width: 100%;
}

hr.fox {
  width: 80%;
  border: none;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  overflow: visible;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

hr.fox::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '^.^';
  position: relative;
  /* Use absolute positioning */
  top: -10px;
  /* Adjust the position as needed */
  background: white;
  /* Uncomment if needed */
  padding: 0 4px;
  /* Uncomment if needed */
}


/* --------------- for the ascii art --------------- */

pre {
  text-align: center
}
  <div class="left" id="left images"></div>

  <div class="center" id="center text">
    <h1>Azul's Blog</h1>

    <pre style="text-align: center">
        ASCII ART
        </pre>
    <p>
      text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
    </p>
    <hr class="fox">
    <p>
      text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
    </p>
    <hr class="fox">
    <p>
      text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
      <br>text<br>
    </p>
    <hr class="fox">
  </div>
  <div class="right" id="right images"></div>
  



code:

You'll probably have to wait until all the images are actually loaded before calling adjustImageVisibility(). Or if you know the image dimensions beforehand, set them explicitly on each element.

And you probaly need to use HTMLImageElement: decode() method for knowing when you can apply your img.getBoundingClientRect() to get your values

As in previous comments  you will probably need to create a promise. Pls check this SO answer

id names should not contain spaces. Are you seeing errors on the console?
